# NullPointerException when adding onClickListener to button in ListView

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I basically have a listview in my app which pulls data from lastFM. The row itself links to the artist track page and the button links to the artists page. I keep getting a `NullPointer` exception when I add 
`artistButton.setOnClickListener(this)`. Could someone help me, this is literally the last piece of functionality I need to implement and i'm stumped.

Thanks in advance to everyone who can help :)

```
public class TrackDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener  {

private static final String debugTag = "TrackDataAdapter";

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<TrackData> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


public TrackDataAdapter (TrackActivity a, ArrayList<TrackData> d)
{
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trackrow, null);

    TextView artistName=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.album_icon);
    TextView trackName=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.track_name);
    Button artistButton = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.track_button);
    artistName.setText(data.get(position).getArtist());
    trackName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).getImageUrl(), image);
    vi.setId(position);
    vi.setOnClickListener(this);
    artistButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return vi;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("OnClick", "button clicked");
    if (v instanceof Button) {
        Log.d("OnClick" , "Instance of button type");
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(data.get(v.getId()).getArtistUrl()));
        this.activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (v instanceof View) {
        Log.d("OnClick" , "Instance of button type");
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(data.get(v.getId()).getTrackUrl()));
        this.activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}    
}
```

This is my trackrow.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rowselector"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/album_icon"
            android:layout_width="32dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/blank" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/track_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album_icon"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="0.5"
            android:textColor="#777777"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artist_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/track_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album_icon"
            android:text="Best Badger: " >
        </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/track_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Artist" >
    </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us your layout file?

Comment: Is `track_button` a `Button` in your `trackrow` xml file?

Comment: [`NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: Sir Pentor - I have added the trackrow.xml to my original post :)
codeMagic - track_button is the id of the button in my trackrow.xml file.  
Abdul - the logcat is too big to post here but it basically gives a null pointer there I add the onClickListener to the track_button.

Answer (score 0):

The line to look at is this:

```
Button artistButton = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.track_button);
```

It looks like artistButton is null after this line. Is the view you are trying to get valid (R.id.track_button) ?

Comment: thanks for replying, I have included the trackrow.xml in the original post, the view is definitely track_button. I'm really confused why its showing as null. Is it something related to the listview maybe?